# Problema al mostrar imagen

Tags: android, imagen

Estoy haciendo una app en Android en la cual tengo un activity y selecciono una imagen de mi galeria para mostrar (hasta ahi no hay problema), luego guardo el Uri de esa imagen en SharedPreferences para poder mostrarla nuevamente cuando carge la APP, pero al cargarla nuevamente no puedo ver la imagen mi codigo:

Abro galeria y Selección de imagen:

```
public void openGallery(){
        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
    }
```

En el metodo resul leo el Uri y guardo en sharedpreferences

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            if (sFoto1.equals("")){

                sFoto1 = imageUri.toString();
                loadImageWithScaleDownWithPicasso (sFoto1, foto1_gallery);
                save_SharedPreferences ("foto1",sFoto1);
            }
        }
    }

private void save_SharedPreferences (String foto, String dato){

        SharedPreferences prefs =
                getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(foto, dato);
        editor.commit();
    }
private void loadImageWithScaleDownWithPicasso(String URL_FOTO, ImageView imageFoto){
        Picasso.get()
                .load(URL_FOTO)
                .resize(2000, 2000)
                .onlyScaleDown()
                .into(imageFoto);
    }
```

Hasta ahí todo ok, pero luego cuando vuelvo a abrir la app, voy a buscar la uri guardada y cuando la cargo la imagen aparece en blanco

```
public void cargar_foto(){
        sFoto1 = load_save_SharedPreferences("foto1");
        if (!sFoto1.equals("")){
            loadImageWithScaleDownWithPicasso (sFoto1, foto1_gallery);
        }
}

private String load_save_SharedPreferences (String foto){

        SharedPreferences prefs =
                getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String data = prefs.getString("foto1", "");
        return data;
    }
```

Alguien sabe cual podría ser el problema? Muchas gracias

---

realice la modificación que me recomendaste y sigue sin funcionar, agregue un if para confirma que el archivo exista pero la imagen sigue sin aparecer

```
String address = getRealPathFromURI(myUri);
        File file = new File(address);
        if(file.exists()) {
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(file)
                    .resize(2000, 2000)
                    .onlyScaleDown()
                    .into(activityMainIVInternet);
        }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, realice las modificaciones que me recomendaste pero sigue sin funcionar, agrege un IF para validar que el archivo exista, el archivo existe pero sigue sin mostrarme la imagen, lo raro es que si uso picasso la uri si me muestra la imagen.

Comment: Por favor no agregues solucionado al título de tu pregunta, en su lugar marca la respuesta que te ayudo como aceptada

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba  si cuando arranca la aplicacion pasa por este if , por ejemplo colocando un **toast**

```
if (sFoto1.equals("")){

            sFoto1 = imageUri.toString();
            loadImageWithScaleDownWithPicasso (sFoto1, foto1_gallery);
            save_SharedPreferences ("foto1",sFoto1);
        }
```

me faltaria saber como esta declarada **sFoto** , porque lo que podria estar sucediendo,es que **sFoto** cuando arranca la aplicacion valga un valor igual a null... por lo tanto, esta condicion nunca se cumpliria sFoto1.equals("")

Si este fuese el caso , la solucion más rapida y simple es darle un valor sFoto="" en el momento de crear la variable, pero tambien puedes controlar la variable sFoto con un condicional parecido a este

```
if ( (sFoto1.equals(""))  || (sFoto==null) ){
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu ayuda, te comento que si entra en el IF y la declaracion de sFoto es:

Comment: private static String sFoto1="";

Answer (score 0):

#### Cargar imagen mediante una URI en un ImageView usando Picasso.

La forma correcta de cargar una imagen usando `Picasso` mediante una `Uri`, es importante obtener la ruta del recurso en el dispositivo, ejemplo:

Tienes la `URI` de una imagen:

```
content://media/external/images/media/7096
```

debes obtener la ruta fisica de la imagen en el dispositivo:

```
 /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20191212_204525.jpg
```

Para esto usa el siguiente método :

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

ahora usando el método anterior se puede obtener la ruta y puedes crear el archivo a cargar:

```
File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(uri));
Picasso.get().load(file).into(imageView);
```

Por lo tanto, en el caso de tu codigo modifica tu metodo `loadImageWithScaleDownWithPicasso()`:

```
   private void loadImageWithScaleDownWithPicasso(String URL_FOTO, ImageView imageFoto){

        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(URL_FOTO);
        //* Usa el método getRealPathFromURI()
        File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(myUri));

        Picasso.get()
                .load(file)
                .resize(2000, 2000)
                .onlyScaleDown()
                .into(imageFoto);

   }
```

Te sugiero revisar la documentacion [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, al intentar utilizar el codigo que me pasaste en la linea (File file = new File(myUri);) me tira el siguiente error "cannot resolve constructor File(Android.Net.Uri)" y me pide que pase myUri a String lo hago pero sigue sin cargar la foto

Comment: @MarianoMagadan perdón es una Uri, se debe obtener el path en el dispositivo y en base a eso cargar la imagen, modifique la respuesta, saludos!