# Problema al cargar imagen con Picasso

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso

estoy tratando de cargar una imagen utilizando la librería Picasso. 
La imagen la quiero cargar a través de un File. Cree la funcion result_picasso la cual llamo desde un boton. Al ejecutarlo no recibo ningun mensaje de error pero en el imageView obtengo una imagen en blanco. Mi código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView activityMainIVInternet;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            activityMainIVInternet = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.activityMainIVInternet);
            result_picaso();
        }

        public void result_picaso (){
            String address = "/storage/1F1A-2617/Download/foto_sd.jpg";
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(new File(address))
                    .resize(2000, 2000)
                    .onlyScaleDown()
                    .into(activityMainIVInternet);
        }
}
```

Alguien sabe cual podría ser el problema?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor no agregues solucionado al título de tu pregunta, en su lugar marca la respuesta que te ayudo como aceptada

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente debes definir que tratas de cargar en tu `ImageView` usando `Picasso`, es diferente una `URI` a una ruta dentro del sistema de archivos, ejemplo:

URI de imagen:

```
 content://media/external/images/media/1270
```

ruta de imagen:

```
 /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20201212_201212.jpg
```

Si tienes una uri de una imagen, usa el método descrito en la pregunta:

[Cargar imagen mediante una URI en un ImageView usando Picasso.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/327168/95)

Si tienes una ruta fisica usa esta para crear un archivo (asegura que el archivo exista) :

```
    String ruta = "/storage/1F1A-2617/Download/foto_sd.jpg";
    File file = new File(ruta);
    if(file.exists()) {
      Picasso.get()
            .load(file)
            .resize(2000, 2000)
            .onlyScaleDown()
            .into(activityMainIVInternet);
    }else{
        //No existe archivo.
    }
```