# Como guardar una imagen en android studio

Tags: java, android

Quería saber como puedo guardar una imagen en mi App una vez obtenida de la galería, para que cuando vuelva a iniciar la App siga estando esa imagen (además de poder volver a cambiarla siempre que el usuario lo desee). Tengo el código de como abrir la galería y seleccionar la imagen, pero no sé como guardarla con SharedPreferences ya que me pide un String pero mi imagen no es un String. Dejo aquí abajo mi código.

Edit: He conseguido resolverlo, dejo el código por si a alguien le sirve también. Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda.

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MiCuentaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {        

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 0;
        private ImageView mImage;
        private Uri mImageUri;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mi_cuenta);

    mImage = findViewById(R.id.ivUsuario);

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String mImageUri = preferences.getString("image", null);

        if (mImageUri != null) {
            mImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mImageUri));
        } else {
            mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_a_photo_black_24dp);
        }

        mImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imageSelect();
            }
        });
    }

    public void imageSelect() {
        permissionsCheck();
        Intent intent;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        }
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Elige una foto"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    public void permissionsCheck() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    mImageUri=data.getData();
                    SharedPreferences preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("image", String.valueOf(mImageUri));
                    editor.commit();
                    mImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);
                    mImage.invalidate();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: podrías guardar el path donde se encuentra la imagen en las sharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo una solución, cuando obtengas la URI de la imagen, puedes guardar este valor en preferencias, así mismo puede obtenerlo usando los métodos:

```
private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";

public void guardaValorURI(Context context, String text) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("uriImagen", text);
    editor.commit();
}



public String obtieneValorURI(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getString("uriImagen", "");
}
```

Puedes guardar el valor de la URI en este punto, dentro del método `onActivityResult()`:

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            imageUri=data.getData();
            imagenUsuario.setImageURI(imageUri);

            //Guarda valor de Uri.
            guardaValorURI(getApplicationContext(), imageUri);
        }
    }
```

y cuando inicie tu aplicación mediante el método :

```
   public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        if(cursor!=null){
          int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
          cursor.moveToFirst();
          return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }else{
          return "";
        }
    }
```

puedes obtener el path de la imagen y agregarlo a tu `ImageView`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mi_cuenta);

    miVista = findViewById(R.id.mLView);
    imagenUsuario = findViewById(R.id.ivUsuario);
    listaUsuario = findViewById(R.id.lvListaUsuario);
    TextView nombreUsuario = findViewById(R.id.tvNombreUsuario);
    nombreUsuario.setText(email);

    //Obtiene uri
    String uriString = obtieneValorURI(getApplicationContext());
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(uriString); 
    //Obtiene path de imagen en dispositivo
    String imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
    File imgFile = new  File(imagePath);
    if(imgFile.exists()){//Revisa si existe imagen
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
         //Agrega imagen a ImageView
         imagenUsuario.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }

    imagenUsuario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            abrirGaleria();
        }
    });
}
```

Revisa estas respuestas donde hago uso del método `getRealPathFromURI()`:

[Imagen pixelada al sacar foto Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/158478/imagen-pixelada-al-sacar-foto-android/158537#158537)

[Problema al mostrar imagen](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/327024/problema-al-mostrar-imagen/327168#327168)

Comment: Buenas Jorge, gracias por la ayuda, necesitaba entender un poco esto de guardar los datos con sharedpreferences, lo que al probar tu código me indica un error en ésta línea. String uriString = obtieneValorURI(getAplicationContext()); donde dice getAplicationContext no entiendo muy bien, osea ahi va un método pero cual? osea el contexto de la misma actividad donde estoy? MiCuentaActivity.this? Un saludo !

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y me tira un error. 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.project.renbooks.MiCuentaActivity.getRealPathFromURI(MiCuentaActivity.java:80)
        at com.project.renbooks.MiCuentaActivity.onCreate(MiCuentaActivity.java:49)

Comment: Perdon, debe ser getApplicationContext() o usa el contexto de la Activity en la que te encuentras como mencionas  MiCuentaActivity.this Recuerda que debes requerir permisos de escritura/lectura  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-android-6-0-read-external

Comment: Realicé una modificación en el método, getRealPathFromURI() ya que la primera ocasión no tienes un valor especificado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, al final he conseguido solucionarlo anoche buscando como un loco, un saludo!