# Problema accediendo a un archivo en Android

Tags: android

Estoy tratando de usar un archivo para enviarlo mediante Post con Retrofit, mi problema es que siempre tengo el error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:182 (No such file or directory)

El permiso lo pido en tiempo de ejecución, la aplicación tiene el API 23 mínimo, obtengo la URI desde el sistema de archivos.

El archivo tiene correcta la ruta, solo que tiene un nombre distinto `("papas.jpg")` pero con la ruta `(/document/image:182)` OK.

Agrego el código:

```
case R.id.adjuntar_archivo:
            if (this.requireContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                requestPermissions(permissions, OPEN_PERMISSION);
            } else {
                openFile();
            }
            break;

private void openFile() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == OPEN_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            if (data.getData() != null) {
                uri = data.getData();
                //hasAttachment se usa para saber si se envía POST con o sin adjunto.
                hasAttachment = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Con `"papas.jpg"` funciona?

Comment: No funciona tampoco, igual la uri que obtengo del intent es el path /document/image:182

Comment: ¿Dónde tienes alojado el archivo? En Android esa ruta (`/document`) no debería existir ni deberías tener permisos para crearla. ¿Qué significa "**El archivo tiene correcta la ruta, solo que tiene un nombre distinto ("papas.jpg") pero con la ruta (/document/image:182) OK.**"? Es bastante confusa esa explicación.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a este que comentas:

"El archivo tiene correcta la ruta, solo que tiene un nombre distinto ("papas.jpg") pero con la ruta (/document/image:182) OK."

la ruta es correcta, pero esta ruta es en realidad una Uri, una Uri como su nombre lo indica es un identificador de recurso uniforme.

Si deseas obtener la ruta del archivo, usa el método que se describe en esta respuesta.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/327168/95

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Usando el método anterior podemos obtener la ruta del archivo:

String imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(uri));
File file = new File(imagePath);

Este es un ejemplo realizado por [@Gowsik K C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5058630/gowsik-k-c) de como subir un archivo mediante Retrofit.

```
 @Multipart
@POST("myrecord")
Call<ResponseBody> addRecord(@Query("token") String token, @Query("userid") int userId,
                             @Query("name") String name, @Part MultipartBody.Part file);



 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if ((requestCode == FILE_SELECT_CODE) && (resultCode == -1)) {

        File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(data.getData()));

        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), getRealPathFromURI(data.getData()));

        MultipartBody.Part multipartBody =MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file",file.getName(),requestFile);

        Call<ResponseBody> responseBodyCall = service.addRecord(token, userId, "fileName", multipartBody);
        responseBodyCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                Log.d("Success", "success "+response.code());
                Log.d("Success", "success "+response.message());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("failure", "message = " + t.getMessage());
                Log.d("failure", "cause = " + t.getCause());
            }
        });

    }
}
```